# Center of circle tangent to hypotenuse in isosceles right triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $AB=AC$ and $\angle BAC=90^{\circ}$. Let $P,Q$ be points on $AB, AC$ respectively such that $PQ=AB$, and let $O$ be the center of the circle passing through $P,Q$ and tangent to $BC$. Show that $OA\parallel BC$.

It would be enough to show that $A,O,P,Q$ are concyclic. It seems like $\triangle OPQ\sim\triangle ABC$, which would imply the concyclic points, but I'm unsure how to do this.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see that $P,Q$ are uniquely determined.

Comment: If $PQ$ is parallel to $BC$ then $O = A$  But, if it is not...then things get more interesting.

Comment: $P,Q$ are arbitrary points on $AB,AC$. The case $O=A$ might be ignored.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see.

Comment: For $OA\parallel BC$, then $O$ must be outside the triangle, right? Which means the circle is not tangent to $BC$ at the midpoint. Which means the length of $OA$ is less than half of $BC$. It also means that $PQ$ is not parallel to $BC$. Also the radius of the circle must be $\sqrt{2}*AB$

Comment: Run out of time to edit previous comment. So continuing it means that $\triangle OPQ\sim\triangle ABC$. In fact $\triangle OPQ$ is equal to the triangles that are the result of bisection of $\triangle ABC$ from $A$ to midpoint of $BC$. The hypotenuses are both equal to $AB$ and the side are both equal to $\sqrt{2}/2 * AB$. And because of Pythagoras the angle located at $O$ is $\pi/2$.

Comment: @Χpẘ sorry how do you get $\triangle OPQ\sim\triangle ABC$? That is the crux of the problem.

Comment: Let's call the midpoint of $BC$ "$D$". Do you see that $\triangle OPQ = \triangle ABD = \triangle ACD$? And you see that $\triangle ACD \sim \triangle ABC$? If not I'll write it up as answer. BTW, my argument is starting with the supposition that $OA \parallel BC$, which is why I said you need to invert my argument.

Comment: @Χpẘ could u write a full response?

Comment: $P$ and $Q$ aren’t entirely arbitrary. For any choice of $P$, the condition $PQ=AB$ completely determines $Q$.

Comment: Also, you have to exclude the case that $AP=AQ$ since then $O=A$ and so there’s no line segment $OA$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the circle through points $P, \,Q$ and tangent to the segment $BC$ be denoted by $k$ and let the point of tangency of $k$ and $BC$ be denoted by $T$. Let line $PQ$ intersect line $BC$ at point $E$ and let us assume, without loss of generality, that point $E$ is located so that $B$ is between $E$ and $C$, while $P$ is between $E$ and $Q$. Then by the tangent-secant theorem (or whatever you call that statement) $$ET^2 = EP \cdot EQ$$

Let the line through point $P$ perpendicular to $AB$ and the line through point $W$ perpendicular to $AC$ intersect at point $R$. Then $APRQ$ is a rectangle and $PQ = AR = AB = AC$.

Denote by $T^*$ the orthogonal projection of $R$ onto the edge $BC$.

**Claim.** *Point $T$ coincides with point $T^*$, i.e. $T\equiv T^*$ meaning that the circle $k$ touches edge $BC$ at point $T^*$*

*Proof:* Draw the circle $k_A$ centered at $A$ and of radius $AB = AC = AR$. Then $k_A$ passes through the points $B, \, R$ and $C$. If you denote say $\angle \, BAR = \alpha$, and observe that the quads $BPT^*R$ and $CQT^*R$ are cyclic, you can chase a bunch of angles and find that $$\angle \, PQT^* = \frac{\alpha}{2} = \angle \, PT^*B$$ (in fact, one can even show that $T^*$ is the incenter of triangle $PQR \, $)

**Edit.** $\angle \, PQT^* = \frac{\alpha}{2} = \angle \, PT^*B$

*Proof of edit:* First, angle $\angle \, RAB = \alpha$ is central for circle $k_A$. Hence, $\angle \, RCB = \frac{1}{2} \, \angle \, RAB = \frac{1}{2} \alpha$. By cyclicity of $CQT^*R$ 
$$\angle \, RQT^* = \angle \, RCT^* = \angle \, RCB =  \frac{1}{2} \alpha$$ However, $APRQ$ is a rectangle, so $\angle \, RQP = \angle \, RAP = \angle \, RAB = \alpha$. Hence
$$\angle \, PQT^* = \angle \, RQP - \angle \, RQT^* = \alpha - \frac{1}{2} \alpha = \frac{1}{2} \alpha$$

Second, $AR = AB$ so $ABR$ is an isosceles triangle, so $$\angle \, ABR = \angle \, ARB = 90^{\circ} - \frac{1}{2} \alpha$$ and since $RP$ is orthogonal to $AB$, 
$$\angle \, PRB = 90^{\circ} - \angle \, ABR = \frac{1}{2} \alpha$$
By cyclicity of $BPT^*R$ 
$$\angle \, PT^*B = \angle \, PRB = \frac{1}{2} \alpha$$ Thus $\angle \, PQT^* = \frac{\alpha}{2} = \angle \, PT^*B$.

The latter equality of angles yields, for example, that triangles $EPT^*$ and $ET^*Q$ are similar. Therefore, $$\frac{EP}{ET^*} = \frac{ET^*}{EQ}$$ which is equivalent to $$ET^{*2} = EP \cdot EQ = ET^2$$ meaning that $ET^* = ET$. Since, by construction, both points $T$ and $T^*$ lie on the line $BC$ and are on the same side of point $B$, one can conclude that $T^* \equiv T$.

**Concluding the proof.** Let  Let $M = PQ \cap AR$. Then $M$ is the midpoint of both diagonal segments $PQ$ and $AR$ of rectangle $APRQ$. Since the point of tangency $T$ of the circle $k$ and the segment $BC$ is the orthogonal projection of point $R$, the center of $k$ lies on the intersection of the line $RT$ and the orthogonal bisector of diagonal $PQ$ through $M$. Again, if you chase some angles, you get  $$\angle \, ORM = \angle \, TRA = 45^{\circ} - \alpha$$ and  $$\angle \, AMO = 90^{\circ} - \angle \, AMQ = 90^{\circ} - 2\,\alpha$$ Therefore, $$\angle \, ROM = \angle \, AMO - \angle \, ORM = 90^{\circ}- 2\,\alpha - 45 + \alpha = 45^{\circ} - \alpha = \angle \, ORM$$ which means that triangle $ORM$ is isosceles with $MO = MR$ which means that $$MO = MR = MA$$ Consequently, triangle $AOR$ is right-angled with $\angle \, AOR = 90^{\circ}$ so line $AO$ is orthogonal to line $RT$. However, $BC$ is also orthogonal to $BC$ (the claim). Thus $AO$ is parallel to $BC$.

Comment: Could you show the details of your angle chase to get $\angle PQT^*=\angle PT^*B$?

Comment: @jlammy I have added it to the proof.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a proof, because I'm starting with the assumption $OA \parallel BC$. Per questioner's request, writing this up as an answer.

Note that $O$ can't be equal to $A$ because $OA$ wouldn't be a line segment.

Let $D$ be the midpoint of $BC$. The circle won't be tangent to $BC$ at $D$. Let's say it is tangent at $E$. Then $OE$ = $AD$ and $OE \parallel AD$. $AD = \sqrt{2}/2 * AB = OE$. Thus radius is $r=\sqrt{2}/2 * AB$. Since $P$ and $Q$ lie on circle $OP = OQ = r$. And it's given that $PQ = AB$. So $\triangle OPQ$ has two sides equal to $r$ and one side equal to $\sqrt{2}r$.

Therefore it is a right triangle (by Pythagoras) with equal sides, so $\,\triangle OPQ \sim \triangle ABC$. Further $\triangle OPQ = \triangle ABD = \triangle ACD$.